# GMail apiclient : exclude promotion and social network mail from inbox label

Tags: python, email, gmail-api, oauth2client

I'm trying to get my last mail using the `apiclient` and `oauth2client` librarys (quickstart from here : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python).

I am curently able to retrieve *all* my last mail, including promotion mail and social network mails (which i don't care).

The script is the following (also if you see some mistake or ways to do it faster, please tell me) :

```
# ... credentials mechanism identical to the quickstart one
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http

# Get the last mails :
last_mails = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds=["INBOX"]).execute()
for mailIds in last_mails["messages"]:
    all_infos = gmail_service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=mailIds["id"]).get(userId="me", id=mailIds["id"]).execute()
    abstract = all_infos["snippet"]

    # Changing json structure
    headers = dict([(x["name"], x["value"]) for x in all_infos["payload"]["headers"]])
    dest = headers["Delivered-To"]
    source = headers["From"]
    title = headers["Subject"]

    print "Mail : %s\nFrom : %s\nTo   : %s\nAbst : %s\n-------" % ( 
            title, source, dest, abstract
            )
```

So my objective is to remove the *promotion* and *social network* mails from the listing. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While sending request to messages.list along with labelIds = "INBOX", include q=category:primary. I tried in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and able to retrieve emails only from inbox.

Response:
  200 OK

```
- Show headers -

  {
  "messages": [
  {
    "id": "14d0078c4b6e7b95",
     "threadId": "14d0078c4b6e7b95"
   },
  {
      "id": "14d0057a75894568",
     "threadId": "14d0057a75894568"
   },
     {
     "id": "14d004211587e8c0",
     "threadId": "14d004211587e8c0"
     },
    {
     "id": "14cfed9aef9e1217",
      "threadId": "14cfed9aef9e1217"
    },
```

Comment: Perfect ! I just found another solution, using `labelIds=["INBOX", "CATEGORY_PERSONAL"]`, but i didn't have all my mails. Your solution is better. Thank you !